# How to setup Grails 3.2 logging for plugin utility class

Tags: grails, logback, grails-plugin

I have a custom Grails 3.2 plugin with a utility class at "com.pbm.fsm.action.ActionNext".  When the plugin runs standalone I can get a log.debug or log.info message from the class.  When I pull it into the main application I cannot get any logging output from the plugin.

The ActionNext class is decorated with @Slf4j.  The source file path is 
`src/main/groovy/com/pbm/fsm/action/ActionNext.groovy`

The application logback file has this entry:
`logger("com.pbm.fsm", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)`

I've tried various paths for the logger but can't get any logging output from the plugin.  What is the fix?

Comment: Are you putting `logger("com.pbm.fsm", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)` in the plugin's config file or the application's config file?

Comment: I have that in the plugin logback.groovy file for running the plugin stand-alone.  That works. I have the same line in the application logback.groovy file.  I have a feeling I need to embellish the path to represent it as a plugin, but nothing I've tried works.

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem.  If you find something that looks like a bug, please feel free to report at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we will investigate.  Best of luck!

Comment: Ah!  Something that just occurred to me.  I am creating the ActionNext class with  def clazz = grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(className).newInstance().  Although it works in the plugin, it may be different when done in the main application?

Comment: I tried the following: I copied the ActionNext class into the main application under a slightly different package as "com.pbm.actions.ActionNext".  I entered this path into the configuration.  The class instance created by the plugin code logged the debug message as expected.   I then changed the path back to the original ActionNext class located in the plugin.  In this case no log messages were produced.  I don't know what this says about anything, but in actuality all "action" classes will be in the main application, so I'm good to go.